# Helicoid and Catenoid

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be isothermal parametrizations of minimal surfaces such that their component functions are pairwise harmonic conjugates, then $X$ and $Y$ are called conjugate minimal surfaces.

My question is: Are the helicoid and the catenoid conjugate minimal surfaces? It seems to be impossible after a short calculation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are conjugate minimal surfaces.

I remember running into calculation errors when I first did this problem, too.  The trick that worked for me was to rotate the helicoid by an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.  Hopefully you should still have isothermal coordinates (check this), but now the Cauchy-Riemann Equations will be satisfied (check this too).

Comment: One way to look at this $\pi / 2$ rotation is as a complex rotation in the [Weierstrass parametrization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%E2%80%93Enneper_parameterization).

Comment: That's pretty cool.